# Woocommerce difference between current_data and data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update a `meta_data` value in WooCommerce using `update_meta_data()` on the `WC_Product_Simple` object.

However, the changes i made are not showing if i navigate to edit the specified product in the Woocommerce/WordPress backend. To debug this, i logged the product meta data i was trying to change to my screen:

```
[8] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                (
                    [current_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1312
                            [key] => _nf_funding_goal
                            [value] => 999
                        )

                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1312
                            [key] => _nf_funding_goal
                            [value] => 30
                        )

                )
```

I tried to change the metadata `_nf_funding_goal` to `999`.  As you can see this change is reflected inside `current_data`. But not in `data`. I'm guessing this is why the changes are not shown when editing a product. Can somebody tell me why, and how to change `data` and not `current_data`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They way you can save a data for a woocommerce product is as follows.

```php
// Get Product Object
$_product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Do the updation, this doesn't acutally update the product.
$_product->update_meta_data('_nf_funding_goal', 999);

// This would acutally call save_post and persist changes to your product
$_product->save(); // You might be missing this!
```

I am suspecting that you must have missed `$_product->save()` in your function.